# Persistencia Listen Firebase

Tags: flutter

Quisiera estar realizando consultas a mi base de datos firebase para estar totalmente actualizado en tiempo real. yo lo realizó con Listen() pero el problema que al cerrar y volver a abrir la aplicación se generan tantas lecturas colmo documentos tengo en la colección. mi idea es que el liste no se cancele cuando cierro la aplicación enviando de esta manera leer todos los documentos casa vez que abro la aplicación

Comment: No se puede. Si cierras la app, se cierran los recursos y al volver a abrirla, deberás consultar los datos otra vez.